# What exactly do the Maven build... choice inside the Eclipse Run As?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-3

I am absolutely new in Maven and I am studying it. I am using **Eclipse**

I have the following doubt: into Eclipse I have a Maven project.

If I select this project and I do right click on it and then I select the **Run As** option I have some choice. What exactly represent these choice? Are Maven tasks or what?

In particular to perform my project I have 2 possible choices:

1. **Maven build**
2. **Maven build...**

What exactly does these tasks? It seems to me that build the project and perform the related unit test. Is it true or am I missing something?

What is the difference between the previous choices. In the tutorial that I am following it is used the **Maven build...** and then set the **clean package** as goals. What exactly do this goal?

Tnx

Comment: A google search would have saved some time https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/running-sect-running-maven-builds.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Developing with Eclipse and Maven - 4.2. Running Maven Builds](https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/running-sect-running-maven-builds.html) doesn't really give any clue about the "Maven build" command.

So:

- the "Maven build..." allows to define a new run configuration
- the "Maven build" allows to choose between the existing user's run configurations or to create a new one if none exists.

About a user's run configuration with "clean package": have you ever used Maven? May be a good tutorial would be a first step... In the mean time -  those goals will:

- delete the *target* sub folder
- rebuild the project in the new empty *target* sub folder
- generate the archive jar-s as specified in the project pom